# Pytorch hidden cell LSTM with mini-batches

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

### Problem

I don't understand how to handle the LSTM hidden cells when training in mini-batches, since the training data is sent to the network in batches of *n* sequences, while only 1 sequence is processed each time during test.

### Code

Specifically, my network is:

```
class Pytorch_LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Pytorch_LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.params = params
        self.hidden_layer_size = params['hidden_layer_size']
        # Define layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = params['in_features'], hidden_size = params['hidden_layer_size'])        
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(params['hidden_layer_size'], params['hidden_layer_size'])
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(params['hidden_layer_size'], params['out_features'])
        self.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1,self.params['batch_size'],self.hidden_layer_size),
                           torch.zeros(1,self.params['batch_size'],self.hidden_layer_size))

    def forward(self, input_seq):        
        lstm_out, self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(input_seq.view(self.params['time_window'],-1,self.params['in_features']), self.hidden_cell)
        linear1_out = self.linear1(lstm_out)
        predictions = self.linear2(linear1_out)
        return predictions[-1]
```

In my `train()` method:

```
def train(self, input_sequence, params, test_idx, final, verbose=True):        

        ....
        ....

        # Model
        self.model = Pytorch_LSTM(params)
        # Let's train the model
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for count_1,seq in enumerate(train_data_batch):      
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                self.model.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1, params['batch_size'], self.model.hidden_layer_size),
                                          torch.zeros(1, params['batch_size'], self.model.hidden_layer_size))   
                y_pred = self.model(seq)     # seq.shape: (n_batches, 25, 4)
                single_loss = mse_loss(y_pred, y_label)    # y_pred.shape, y_label.shape : (batch_size, 4)
```

This trains the model in mini-batches, I believe correctly. 
When I test it, I only have one single sequence per time, instead of multiple batches. In my `test()`:

```
for count,seq in enumerate(val_data[j]):                   
    y_pred = self.model(seq)           # seq.shape: (25,4)
    single_loss = mse_loss(y_pred, y_label)
```

This returns the error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 1, 100), got (1, 704, 100)
```

where `n_batches`= 704.

How should I handle the hidden_cell?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `(h_0, c_0)` parameters to the lstm on each call of shape (1, batch_size, 100). batch_size is for parallel processing and is arbitrary but you are hardcoading every time in

```py
self.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1,self.params['batch_size'],self.hidden_layer_size),
                    torch.zeros(1,self.params['batch_size'],self.hidden_layer_size))
```

This `hidden_cell` is `h_0` and `c_0` parameters i.e., the initial values of hidden and cell state.

Trying to pass (1, batch_size, 100) sized array is unnecessary as [it defaults to zero](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm) vector of the required size by itself.

Just get rid of the `self.hidden_cell` and only pass `input_seq` to the `self.lstm` in `forward` method. It should work